# column vector times row vector to form a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I want to do matrix multiplication between a column vector and a row vector, How do I do that?

Here is an example of what the multiplication do `[1,2,3]^T*[1,2,3] =[[1,2,3],[2,4,6],[3,6,9]]`. Here is what I tried: `np.array([[i] for i in x]).dot(x)` but it doesn't work. Here x is an arbitrary numpy array of numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

[numpy.matmul](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul)

Notes from the documentation

The behavior depends on the arguments in the following way.

- If both arguments are 2-D they are multiplied like conventional
  matrices.
- If either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack of
  matrices residing in the last two indexes and broadcast accordingly.
- If the first argument is 1-D, it is promoted to a matrix by
  prepending a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication the
  prepended 1 is removed.
- If the second argument is 1-D, it is promoted to a matrix by
  appending a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication the
  appended 1 is removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with numpy

```
import numpy as np

x = np.asarray([1,2,3])
matrix = x[:,None] * x[None,:]
```

The command `x[:,None]` makes the `x` 1d-array into a (3,1) 2d-array, and vice versa for `x[None,:]`. The multiplication between a (3,1) and a (1,3) matrix yields a (3,3) matrix, where the multiplication is done element-wise. `np.matmul`, `np.dot` or the `@`-operator between the two arrays would also work. This is basically a more efficient version of your own approach, which would have worked if you made the following slight modification:

```
np.array([[i] for i in x]).dot([[x]])
```

Alternatively you can do it with Einstein summation:

```
np.einsum('i,j->ij', x, x)
```

The syntax 'i,j->ij' means that you want a matrix who's first axis has the same dimensionality of the first array and who's second axis has the same dimensionality as the second array.